# Performance Issue in Java

Tags: java

I am facing a performance issue in my code in Java. I have to count the frequency of each object created by a process. The type of object is "Node" given below.
Currently I have solved this problem using HashMap type technique given below in test1. However this process is very slow because my simulation generates 100s of millions of object. Moreover I have to split the String during each iteration and then re concatenate and so on. So I was thinking to apply technique somehow like given below in test2. But HashMap considers each new object as a new entry regardless of the contents within the object.
I am wondering if someone knows how to solve this problem efficiently.

```
public class NewMain {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
         String[] a={"c","d"};
         int[] b={1,2};

    Map<String, Integer> test1=new HashMap<>();
    test1.put(new Node(a, b).toString(), 1);
    test1.put(new Node(a, b).toString(), 3);
    System.out.println(test1.size()); // size is 1

         //////////////////////////
         Map<Node, Integer> test2=new HashMap<>();
         test2.put(new Node(a, b), 1);
         test2.put(new Node(a, b), 3);
         System.out.println(test2.size()); // size is 2

}
}
    class Node{
    String[] a;
    int[] b;

public Node(String[] a, int[] b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
public String toString(){
 String result=null;
    for(String e:a)
        result+=e+"|";
    for(int e:b)
        result+=e+"|";
    return result;   
}

}
```

Comment: Override `hashCode` for your `Node` class?

Comment: any particular reason you use `String` and not `Node` as the key?

Comment: In test2 I have used Node as key but each time I insert it into HashMap it is considered as new key. So at the end I will end up with millions of entries in HashMap.

Comment: How can I override hashCode? any Suggestion

Comment: Your `toString` may be a bottleneck (or it may not - have you tried profiling to determine if it is?) as string concatenation can be very expensive. Have a look at [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for much more efficient concatenation.

Comment: Let me elaborate it further. I am running a simulation. The simulation has millions of iterations. During each iteration I record the state of simulation in Object Node. The simulation can have only 500 different states. I just wanted to know the frequency of each state at the end of process. For this reason I concatenate each state variable in a string, and then count the number of strings in HashMap. This works fine but it is very slow. So I was thinking to avoid string processing, like concatenation and then splitting etc. Any suggestion how to do it efficiently.

Comment: If you are using eclipse, you can auto-generate the definition of `hashCode` and `equals` method using `source-->generate hashCode and equals` pop-up menu. Just right click the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this within your `Node` class:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 1;
    for(String e:a)
        result = result * 31 + e.hashCode();
    for(int e:b)
        result = result * 31 + e;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
}
```

This tells Java that one should compare objects by comparing their hash codes - the default is just to compare pointers, and ensures that the hash code is calculated based on the contents of the class. This will give you a result of 1 for your `test2.size()` call.

---

Or, based on @bjlee72's suggestion above, Eclipse gives me:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(a);
    result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(b);
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Node other = (Node) obj;
    if (!Arrays.equals(a, other.a))
        return false;
    if (!Arrays.equals(b, other.b))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! just a quick question. I want to use only string array "a". So I removed second loop in hashCode(). But will it be a problem to avoid even the first loop and just use                            public int hashCode(){return a.hasCode();}. It is gives the correct result though but I am wondering if there will be any collision for large number of contents.

Comment: Now you point it out, my `equals` code does indeed run the risk of collisions, but the Eclipse version does not. Guessing at the implementation of `Map`, it might first do a `hashCode` for a quick compare, then `equals` to check if it is just a collision or an actual match. Please choose the Eclipse version over mine as it will be more reliable.